# Slicing series with t-test

Tags: anova, t-test, sequential-pattern-mining

I am trying to develop a system for automated performance regression detection. Usually this boils down to setting range for the performance counters manually (e.g. no more than 5% drop in throughput vs. baseline/average of N last results) but I wanted something that could also detect smaller drops that stay in the results for many observations. I could do different thresholds for floating averages etc., but I was thinking about something statistically more sound.

My naive approach was to analyze the last N values (up to last detected change) and do a t-test for x<sub>1</sub> .. x<sub>k</sub> vs. x<sub>k+1</sub> .. x<sub>n</sub> for each `k` (requiring the subset to have at least few values) at 95% confidence level. I was wondering why I am getting many false positives on real data, so I've generated random series from normally distributed data with the same mean and I've observed the same.

I think that my request to see no false positives is contradicting the set confidence level - is that correct?

Can you suggest a better approach, besides increasing the confidence level? Am I completely off path?
False positives would be more frequent since in fact I will have 10s of counters for each nightly run and the chances multiply.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some other issues related to the interpretation of these sequential test results, but one small suggestion is that you could use the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) to reduce the number of false positives. It will, however, come at the cost of more false negatives.